# Why does IDEA not refresh project settings after build.sbt has changed?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

- sbt **0.13.5**
- IntelliJ IDEA **14.1.1**
- OS: Windows

As weird as it sounds but I changed `build.sbt` file in IntelliJ IDEA from `"edu.arizona.sista" %% "processors" % "3.3"` to `"edu.arizona.sista" %% "processors" % "5.2"` and also changed the Scala version from `2.10.4` to `2.11.4`.

I rebuilt the code in IntelliJ and run it and the output had **not** changed. I did the same process using SBT in console and it worked.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have "Use auto-import" checked in SBT preferences?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** Run `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` in IntelliJ IDEA to...invalidate caches and start over.

[image]

You may also want to check out `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > SBT` in `Preferences` (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> under Mac OS X) and make sure that `Use auto-import` project-level setting checkbox is selected.

[image]

If all above didn't help, file an issue in [the Scala project of IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A%20Scala).

Comment: Ugh the hammer of Thor "Invalidate Caches / Restart..." :( (perhaps present the solutions in reverse order? first make sure it's refreshed/refreshing, then hammer of Thor?)

Comment: it's not working with hammer of Thor! tomorrow I will file an issue!

Comment: Why IntelliJ cannot use SBT as is in console!?

Comment: Why do all those IDEs have (a) hidden button(s) for manual propeller swinging? Current settings should be applied automatically!